# Spring boot uploading file error when try bigger file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this upload method:

```
try {
        Files.createDirectories(filesPath);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    for (MultipartFile file : Arrays.asList(files)) {
        try {
            // Get the file and save it somewhere
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(filesPath + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It work well, but when i try upload bigger file around 1,5GB i get this error:

```
Invalid string length
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to adjust two properties if you want to allow uploads of such big files.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Then it is better to use `MultipartFile.getInputStream()` to read the contents of the file.

You might also use `IOUtils.copy()` from Apache Commons IO to simplify your job.

Comment: Alternatively, [`MultipartFile#transferTo`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo(java.nio.file.Path)) allows saving a `MultipartFile` directly using a `Path` object.